# Extract specific value with AWK?

Tags: awk

I have this file, `pepe`:

```
1.2345 2.3456 3.4567
4.5678 5.6789 6.8905
```

I want to print the value located at the second row and the third column:

```
6.8905
```

What I have tried is:

```
awk 'NR==2,{print $3}'
```

But, it is not working

Comment: please define "it is not working". perhaps you just need to elide the `,`

Comment: When asking for help with a script that produces error messages, always include the error message(s) in your question so it's easiest for us to help you. In this case awk would have printed an error message pointing to just after that comma and saying "syntax error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need:

```
awk 'FNR == 2 {print $3}' /path/to/pepe
```

Where `FNR == 2` matches the second row for which we print the third column: `{print $3 }`